# Call kotlin completion in java

Tags: java, android, functional-programming, kotlin

I have a kotlin web request method that takes a function as a parameter.
Due to how one of my classes is set up, I need to keep it as a java class but I need to call the web request method from the java class.

I have a class called `Lock` that I am fetching from my database using `Fuel`

My kotlin method is as follows

```
fun fetchLocks(completion: (Array<Lock>) -> Unit) {
  // asynchronous api calls that aren't relevant.
  completion(locks)
}
```

I know that this method works and am able to call it from a kotlin file

```
FuelHelper().fetchLocks { locks ->
  Do stuff with my locks
}
```

The issue I am having is getting the proper syntax in order to call this method in java.

```
new FuelHelper().fetchLocks();
```

The parameter java expects is `(Function1<?super Lock[], Unit>)`

I have tried for a while now and am unable to get past this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using java 8 syntax.

```
new FuelHelper().fetchLocks(locks -> {
    ...
});
```

Or without lambda

```
new FuelHelper().fetchLocks(new Function1<Lock[], Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(Lock[] locks) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution. Saved lots of time!

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly what it says - You have to pass an object implementing interface `Function1` (source from generated file `Functions.kt`):

```
/** A function that takes 1 argument. */
public interface Function1<in P1, out R> : Function<R> {
    /** Invokes the function with the specified argument. */
    public operator fun invoke(p1: P1): R
}
```

In your case you create an anonymous class the same way you do for all small listeners like onClicks etc.:

```
    new FuelHelper().fetchLocks(new Function1<Lock[], Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(Lock[] locks) {
            // handle locks
            return null;
        }
    });
```